# AS3 central event dispatcher shared between instances (not static)

Tags: actionscript-3, events, loose-coupling

I'm building a flash app (just AS3 with FlashDevelop) and I'm having some trouble keeping things loosely coupled around the event system.  I've done a lot of reading about central event systems and static eventdispatchers but they don't quite fit the bill for me.

What I'm building is similar to a video player.  I have a **Player** class which is the parent of all the other little parts of the app.  The **Player** class extends **Sprite** and I've currently designed it so that you could instantiate multiple **Player's** and put them on the stage.  I also have a **Controller** class which extends **EventDispatcher** and I dispatch all my events through this class.  It's a central event class.

**The problem is that I need to pass around a reference to this class so that all the other classes can dispatch and listen through it.**  Passing around the reference works but it's the exact opposite of loose coupling.  I know I could make a static EventDispatcher that all the classes could see but then if I had two or three Player's on the stage they would all hear each others events.

How can I create a type of *sandbox* that will allow all the child classes of a **Player** instance to be aware of the central dispatcher without passing a reference or making it static?

Comment: You could use injection instead of passing around a reference 'manually'.

Comment: BTW I'm not sure it's a very good idea to use a 'central dispatcher' in a custom component. I can see the benefit in a large scale application where one module must talk to the other and you don't want to bubble through the entire displaylist. But for something as simple as a video player I fail to see the point.

Comment: Well it's more complicated than just a video player but I didn't want to elaborate.  What do you mean by injecting?  Let's say the Controller belongs to the Player but I want a far off UI piece to listen to Controller (ex: sidebar.widgets.notemaker).  Do I need to pass the instance of Controller to Sidebar, Widgets, and then Notemaker?

Comment: By 'injecting' I mean: have an 'Inversion of Control'-framework (IoC) do the passing around for you. If only NoteMaker requires a dispatcher, neither Sidebar nor Widgets will have to know about it. The IoC will scan/watch the displaylist and 'inject' your dispatcher wherever it finds a property that meets the right conditions. Some frameworks that include an IoC are RobotLegs and Parsley but there's many more.

Comment: Come to think about it, injection will probably not be your best bet either. You'll run into the same problem as with the static dispatcher: you need a separate instance of Controller for each chain in the displaylist. It can probably be configured with some of the IoC-frameworks, but it feels so clunky. What's so wrong about bubbling?

Comment: The problem with bubbling is that not every class is in the displaylist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out what I was really trying to understand was loose-coupling using something like **dependency injection**.

I never ended up doing this in any AS3 projects as I don't do much of it anyway.  Having done more C# recently I more easily grasped this concept using libraries such as **StructureMap** and **Ninject**.

For AS3 you could use a framework like [Robotlegs](http://www.robotlegs.org/).  This will probably change the way you code AS3 and may not be for all developers/situations.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to use [my static dispatcher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4040300/as3-flex-4-most-practical-way-to-find-nested-children/4046561#4046561), this one has an ID mechanism that allows to tell which Player instance dispatches an event.